# Multiple Regex Replace, does it create multiple strings?

Tags: c#, regex

So I need to perform multiple Regex Replaces, I was wondering if this was bad practice since it might create multiple new strings ? Is there a better way to do this ?

```
var AllVariants = Regex.Replace(s, "5|S", "[5|S]");
AllVariants = Regex.Replace(AllVariants, "6|G", "[6|G]");
AllVariants = Regex.Replace(AllVariants, "8|B", "[8|B]");
AllVariants = Regex.Replace(AllVariants, "4|A", "[4|A]");
AllVariants = Regex.Replace(AllVariants, "1|I", "[1|I]");
AllVariants = Regex.Replace(AllVariants, "0|O", "[O|0]");
```

Comment: Consider using a plain and simple loop through you string with a switch statement and a `StringBuilder`. Creating a few extra strings doesn't really matter because the garbage collector handles it well. However, your code iterates through the string multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you will browse the string 6 times, if you put all in one expression, you will browse the string only once.

```
string[] corr = {"[5|S]", "[6|G]", "[8|B]", "[4|A]", "[1|I]", "[0|O]"};

Regex reg = new Regex(@"([5S])|([6G])|([8B])|([4A])|([1I])|([0O])");

var AllVariants = reg.Replace(s, delegate(Match m) {
    for (int key = 0; key < corr.Length; ++key)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[key+1].Value) == false) break;
    return corr[key];
});
```

Comment: Hey Casimir, I see what you are saying alright. From your answer I don't see how the replacement will give me the same end result however. I.e if I came across the char "5" i want it to be replaced by [5|S]. I don't see how your answer does this ?

Comment: @StevieB: Sorry, I was convinced that you wanted to replace the literal string `5|S` by `[5|S]`. In this case, you need to use the matchevaluator delegate. I will edit my answer.

Comment: just getting a build error with that code that not all paths return a value

Comment: hey thanks for edit but just can't seem to compile above the code even after fixing the missing for value for k. It is complaining it's cant resolve symbol key in return statement

Comment: @StevieB: Sorry, but I can't test my code now (virtualbox update). Wait a little...